# codeigniter session generates internal server error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I already load session libraries in *autoload.php* by

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

At first, I got '500 - Internal Server Error' when my codeigniter reach:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
```

After googling on web, I changed my *config.php* `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']` from `FALSE` to `TRUE` and I found that code generates '500 - Internal Server Error' too.

It's all fine when I use my localhost, but the problem started when I uploaded it on some web hosting. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: What is in your error logs? Check with your host for their location if you don't know.

Comment: Check your error log file . Also you need to post some more codes .

Comment: error log: `upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream` @AzizSaleh

Comment: Are `base_url()` and `.htaccess` code changed to new server values respectively?

Comment: is it trying to send a massive cookie that is far to big for the header? You give no idea how much data you are putting in the session, this is all serialized then encrypted so the sizes increases vary rapidly. I would recommend using the database or native sessions if this is the case.